# Why use new and delete at all?

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

I'm new to C++ and I'm wondering why I should even bother using new and delete? It can cause problems (memory leaks) and I don't get why I shouldn't just initialize a variable without the new operator. Can someone explain it to me? It's hard to google that specific question.

Comment: `Stack Overflow is the answer`.(Pun intended). Your stack is much smaller than the heap. Read about the difference between stack and heap memory in C++.

Comment: @tgmath: you can use standard containers to keep objects, and they won't use much stack. also you can have global containers to manage objects.

Comment: "I don't get why i shouldn't just initialize a variable without the new operator" You may and should use stack memory until you have a good reason to use the heap: "int i=5;" is perfectly valid.

Comment: @tgmath interpreted your question to mean why use dynamic memory. One could interpret your question to mean why use manual dynamic memory. In modern C++ you can use smart pointers etc and never have to use new or delete again, but still using dynamic memory.

Comment: @NeilKirk That doesn't answer the question, and in addition, is bad advice in general.  There are cases where smart pointers are appropriate, but they aren't as common as is often made out: if you can solve the problem without dynamic allocation, you should, and in the most frequent reason for needing dynamic allocation---arbitrary lifetime determined by program logic---smart pointers aren't appropriate either.

Comment: @JamesKanze Sorry if I was not clear. I didn't mean to say use lots of dynamic memory. I meant, if you are using dynamic memory, there is no need to use it manually any more. 99% of the time modern C++ code should have no news or deletes.

Comment: But that is simply false.  The most frequent case where dynamic allocation is where the lifetime is determined by program logic, and there's no smart pointer which will handle this (and no need for one).

Answer (score 6):

For historical and efficiency reasons, C++ (and C) [memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) is explicit and manual.

Sometimes, you might allocate on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (e.g. by using [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s or [alloca(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html)). However, that is not always possible, because

1. stack size is limited (depending on the platform, to a few kilobytes or a few megabytes).
2. memory need is not always [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) or [LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_%28computing%29). It does happen that you need to allocate memory, which would be freed (or becomes useless) much later during execution, in particular because it might be the result of some function (and the caller - or its caller - would release that memory).

You definitely should read about [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) and [dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#Dynamic_memory_allocation). In some languages (Java, Ocaml, Haskell, Lisp, ....) or systems, a GC is provided, and is in charge of releasing memory of useless (more precisely *unreachable*) data. Read also about [weak references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference). Notice that most *GCs* need to scan the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) for local pointers.

<sup>Notice that it is possible, but difficult, to have quite efficient garbage collectors (but usually not in C++). For *some* programs, Ocaml -with a generational copying GC- is faster than the equivalent C++ code -with explicit memory management.</sup>

Managing memory explicitly has the advantage (important in C++) that you don't pay for something you don't need. It has the inconvenience of putting more burden on the programmer.

In C or C++ you might sometimes consider using the [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://hboehm.info/gc/). With C++ you might *sometimes* need to use your own allocator, instead of the default [std::allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator). Read also about [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting), [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [std::weak_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr), and the [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom, and the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) (in C++, becoming the rule of 5). The recent wisdom is to avoid explicit `new` and `delete` (e.g. by using standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and smart pointers).

Be aware that the most difficult situation in managing memory are arbitrary, perhaps circular, graphs (of reference).

On Linux and some other systems, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is a useful tool to hunt [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Comment: Garbage collection is definitely a useful tool, and it's available in C++ as well (the Boehm collector).  Unlike the other languages you cite, however, C++ has value semantics, so the use of dynamically allocated memory is limited, often just to objects with a lifetime which depends on program logic.  And garbage collection doesn't solve lifetime issues (even in languages which have it---you still often need a special `dispose` function, or something similar, which must be explicitly called).  In C++, the main motivation for garbage collection is safety.

Answer (score 3):

The alternative, allocating on the stack, will cause you trouble as stack sizes are often limited to Mb magnitudes and you'll get lots of value copies. You'll also have problems sharing stack-allocated data between function calls.

There are alternatives: using `std::shared_ptr` (C++11 onwards) will do the `delete` for you once the shared pointer is no longer being used. A technique referred to by the hideous acronym RAII is exploited by the shared pointer implementation. I mention it explicitly since most resource cleanup idioms are RAII-based. You can also make use of the comprehensive data structures available in the C++ Standard Template Library which eliminate the need to get your hands too dirty with explicit memory management.

But formally, **every** `new` must be balanced with a `delete`. Similarly for `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Comment: +1 for std::shared_ptr, it makes life a lot easier in many situations (but not all).  I also found std::unique_ptr to be very useful.

Comment: Unlike `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` isn't really RAII; it implements a very particular lifetime management policy, which is only occasionally appropriate.

Comment: @jiandingzhe It's just a tool, like any other.  I don't hate it; I use it when appropriate.  I do hate people recommending it for everything, without knowing whether it would be appropriate or not.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed in many cases `new` and `delete` are not needed, you can just use standard containers instead and leaving to them the allocation/deallocation management.

One of the reasons for which you may need to use allocation explicitly is for objects where the identity is important (i.e. they are not just values that can be copied around).

For example if you have a gui "window" object then making copies probably doesn't make sense and thus you're more or less ruling out all standard containers (they're designed for objects that can be copied and assigned). In this case if the object needs to survive the function that creates it probably the simplest solution is to just allocate explicitly it on the heap, possibly using a smart pointer to avoid leaks or use-after-delete.

In other cases it may be important to avoid copies not because they're illegal, but just not very efficient (big objects) and explicitly handling the instance lifetime may be a better (faster) solution.

Another case where explicit allocation/deallocation may be the best option are complex data structures that cannot be represented by the standard library (for example a tree in which each node is also part of a doubly-linked list).

Answer (score 2):

Modern C++ styles often frown on explicit calls to `new` and `delete` outside of specialized resource management code.

This is not because the stack/automatic storage is sufficient, but rather because RAII smart resource owners (be they containers, shared pointers, or something else) make almost all direct memory wrangling unnessecary.  And as the problem of memory management is often error prone, this makes your code more robust, easier to read, and sometimes faster (as the fancy resource owners can use techniques you might not bother with everywhere).

This is exemplified by the rule of zero: write no destructor, copy/move assign, copy/move constructor.  Store state in smart storage, and have it handle it for you.

None of the above applies when you yourself are writing smart memory owning classes.  This is a rare thing to need to do, however.  It also requires C++14 (for `make_unique`) to get rid of the penultimate excuse to call `new`.

Now, the free store is still used, just not directly, under the above style.  The free store (aka heap) is needed because automatic storage (aka the stack) only supports really simple object lifetime rules (scope based, compile time deterministic size and count, FILO order).  As runtime sized and counted data is common, and object lifetime is often not that simple, the free store is used by most programs.  Sometimes copying an object around on the stack is enough to make the simple lifetime less of a problem, but at other times identity is important.

The final reason is stack overflow.  On some C++ implementations the stack/automatic storage is seriously constrained in size.  What more is that there is rarely if ever a reliable failure mode when you put to much stuff in it.  By storing large data on the free store, we can reduce the chance the stack will overflow.

Comment: The first statement is definitely false.  Any C++ style will (or should) frown on unnecessary dynamic allocations, regardless of where or how they occur.  And for objects whose lifetime depends on program logic (the most common reason for dynamic allocation), an explicit `new` and `delete` (often `delete this`, as the object itself reacts to an event) are really the only way to go.

Comment: @jamezkanze store the data in a `unique_ptr`.  `.reset()` when no longer needed.  This clearly indicates what pointer is owning, makes leaks nearly impossible (containing object must leak for resource to leak, and if applied recursively the containing object did not leak), and has nearly zero overhead (just possibly redundant checks at destruction & zeroing, if compiler cannot prove it redundant).  It may not be your style, but I did not claim every style.

Comment: And what does that buy you except added complexity?

Comment: @jameskanze you can locally prove lack of leaks?  You get type enforced documentation about what pointers own?  If you have never leaked anything, and nobody has ever leaked anything when modifying your code, then it buys nothing.  In practice, leaks are common, and this style adds next to zero complexity, while eliminating entire categories of bugs.

Comment: Obviously, you can prove nothing "locally", because "locally" doesn't include the desired lifetime.  But then, using the usual smart pointers doesn't actually prove anything either; I've found that `shared_ptr` are often a source of leaks (because of cycles).  And _no_ pointer owns.  Otherwise: leaks are very, very rare, because we only allocate dynamically things which need a lifetime defined by program logic.  For the most part, objects which are allocated dynamically are self contained, and aren't "owned" at all, unless temporarily (e.g. by a transaction).

Comment: @james I was talking about `unique_ptr`, not `shared_ptr`.  They are both smart pointers, in that they act like pointers and manage lifetime, but are otherwise very different.  `shared_ptr` has overhead, and often makes reasoning about lifetime harder.  `unique_ptr` has nearly zero overhead, and makes reasoning about lifetime easier.  Conflating the two implies uou should try `unique_ptr` more: I would never recommend wholesale `shared_ptr` sweeping.

Comment: You can't use `unique_ptr` for something whose lifetime might last beyond the lifetime of the pointer.  (`unique_ptr` _is_ essential if you can't bring the object fully to life in the constructor; you need to manage it until it is capable of handling its own lifetime.  At which time, you call `release` on the pointer.)  And for long lived objects: depending on the architecture, it will be either `delete this`, or the delete will be in the commit phase of the transaction, by the transaction.  So where do you put the `unique_ptr`?

Answer (score 2):

First, if you don't need dynamic allocation, don't use it.

The most frequent reason for needing dynamic allocation is that
the object will have a lifetime which is determined by the
program logic rather than lexical scope.  The `new` and
`delete` operators are designed to support explicitly managed
lifetimes.

Another common reason is that the size or structure of the
"object" is determined at runtime.  For simple cases (arrays,
etc.) there are standard classes (`std::vector`) which will
handle this for you, but for more complicated structures (e.g.
graphs and trees), you'll have to do this yourself.  (The usual
technique here is to create a class representing the graph or
tree, and have it manage the memory.)

And there is the case where the object must be polymorphic, and
the actual type won't be known until runtime.  (There are some
tricky ways of handling this without dynamic allocation in the
simplest cases, but in general, you'll need dynamic allocation.)
In this case, `std::unique_ptr` might be appropriate to handle
the `delete`, or if the object must be shared, `std::shared_ptr`
(although usually, objects which must be shared fall into the
first category, above, and so smart pointers aren't
appropriate).

There are probably other reasons as well, but these are the
three that I've encountered the most often.

Answer (score 1):

Only on simple programs you can know beforehand how much memory you'd use. In general you can not foresee how much memory you'd use.

However with modern C++11 you generally rely on standard libraries like `vector` and `map` for memory allocation, and the use of smart pointers helps you avoid memory leaks, so you don't really need to use `new` and `delete` explicitly by hand.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using **New** then your object stores in **Heap**, and it remains there until you don't manually delete it. but in the case **without using new** your object goes in **Stack** and it destroys automatically when it goes out of scope. 
**Stack** is set to a fix size, so if there is no any block for assign a new object then **Stack Overflow** occurs. This often happens when a lot of nested functions are being called, or if there is an infinite recursive call. If the current size of the **heap** is too small to accommodate new memory, then more memory can be added to the heap by the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason may be if you are explicitly calling an external library or API with a C-style interface.  Setting up a callback in such cases often means context data must be supplied and returned in the callback, and such an interface usually provides only a 'simple' void* or int*.  Allocating an object or struct with new is appropriate for such actions, (you can delete it later in the callback, should you need to).

Comment: I've seen a lot of people use `static` objects for this.  But yes.  On the other hand, the passage by `void*` means that you have to be careful.  A common idiom sees the callback casting back to `Base*`, in order to call a virtual member function; if the callee passes `new Derived` directly to the `void*`, undefined behavior results.

Comment: statics are not thread-safe.  Also, it's not uncommon to have more than one callback set up at one time.

Comment: I didn't say it was a good idea; I said that I've seen a lot of people who do it.  In the case of `pthread_create`, for example, which clearly poses the problem.  (In fact, you _can_ work around this, by using a `pthread_cond_t` to only advance in the starting thread once the child thread has copied the value into a local variable.  Boost threads do this, for example, to ensure the lifetime of any temporaries you might have passed into the constructor.)