# Create Title for popup window

Tags: javascript, c#

**How to set title on a Pop-up window?**
when click on a links I open a pop-up using window.open(url) method of javascript. i want different title for different link.

Comment: To open popup what are you using?

Comment: possible replica of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501424/set-title-in-the-window-popup

Comment: I am using window.open(url) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use below code**

```
window.open("mywindow.html", "mywindow title", 
   "left=460,top=200,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,  width=400,height=250");
```

**Properties**

- `url` - for redirecting page name
- `title` - for window title
- `left`,`top` - for window position
- `height`/`width` - for window height/width
- `scrollbars` - it enables scrollbars on window.

**Edit : updated answer**

```
if(Request.QueryString["parameter1]=="demo")
{ 
   Page.Title = "Demo title";
}
else
{ 
   Page.Title = "different  title";
}
```

Comment: It doesn't set the title of a popup window. I tried, u can also try  it for ur satisfaction. By editing on this link : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open2

Comment: @SanjaySoni - see the updated answer - do you use .aspx page or .html ??

Comment: i am using .aspx page for my url. I want different title for different links on a same page for a single child page. Your updated answer will set a static title for every links popups.

Comment: @SanjaySoni - if you are using .aspx page than you can set title using `Page.Title = "new title";` in `Page_Load`event the base of `Request.QueryString[""]` you can set different different titles

Comment: Thanx, i got answer, It works. Thanx again for solving my problem.

Comment: It is a good way to set dynamic title on click on different links using Page.Title = "Demo" in code behind.

Comment: @SanjaySoni - glad to help you :). click on 'upvote' and 'correct' on answer which will help others to get the correct solution thanks

Comment: I don't have minimum points to upvote an answer. So if u give me some then i can upvote for u. one more on this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423270/why-use-new-and-delete-at-all/26423714#26423714

Answer (score 0):

Use the .dialog("option", "title"   capability.  For example:

$("#someEvent").dialog("option", "title", your title);